# Pivot a pandas dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a sample data frame like below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Gender':['Male','Male','Male','Male','Female','Female','Female','Female','Male','Male','Male','Male','Female','Female','Female','Female'],
                'Year' :[2008,2008,2009,2009,2008,2008,2009,2009,2008,2008,2009,2009,2008,2008,2009,2009],
           'rate':[2.3,3.2,4.5,6.7,5.6,3.2,3.5,2.6,2.3,3.2,4.5,6.7,5.6,3.2,3.5,2.6],
           'Heading':['TNMAB123','TNMAB123','TNMAB123','TNMAB123','TNMAB123','TNMAB123','TNMAB123','TNMAB123',
                     'TNMAB456','TNMAB456','TNMAB456','TNMAB456','TNMAB456','TNMAB456','TNMAB456','TNMAB456'],
           'target':[31.2,33.4,33.4,35.2,35.2,36.4,36.4,37.2,31.2,33.4,33.4,35.2,35.2,36.4,36.4,37.2],
            'day_type':['wk','wkend','wk','wkend','wk','wkend','wk','wkend','wk','wkend','wk','wkend','wk','wkend','wk','wkend']})
```

I would like to transpose/pivot them to get the output like as shown below but for my code, it throws an error as shown below

```
df1.pivot(index='Year', columns='Heading', values='rate')
```

With the help of SO post, I wrote this but for 3 columns, I am not sure how to make it work?

```
df1 = df1.pivot_table(index=['Year','Gender','day_type'],columns='Heading',values='rate').unstack()
df1.columns = ['_'.join(i) for i in df1.columns.tolist()]
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below where each year is made as a row and all the corresponding entries for that year are made as columns.

Please note I haven't filled in the values as table column structure is more important.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `map`, also you need `unstack` two `level`

```
df1 = df1.pivot_table(index=['Year','Gender','day_type'],columns='Heading',values='rate').unstack([1,2])
df1.columns=df1.columns.map('_'.join)
df1
      TNMAB123_Female_wk  ...  TNMAB456_Male_wkend
Year                      ...                     
2008                 5.6  ...                  3.2
2009                 3.5  ...                  6.7
[2 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: Fantastic. It works. It works. But only issue is few of my columns repeat twice in my data? Meaning there is an extra entry of the same column (but empty/blank values). Upvoted

Comment: `df1.pivot_table(index=['Year','Gender','day_type'],columns='Heading',values='rate'，aggfunc='sum')` @TheGreat

Comment: May I know why do we need to do `aggfunc=sum`?

Comment: @TheGreat pivot is to reshape, with aggfunc, it will make the duplicate agg with sum, or you can do `df1=df1.sum(level=0,axis=1)`

Comment: No, the issue right now is for ex: I have two columns. `readata123_Female_wk` and `realdata123  _Female_wk`.  Note the gap in between `hyphen`. The former has proper values whereas the latter (incorrect space issue) column is empty

Comment: @TheGreat then you need to do the str.strip for all the columns .